# How to disable a button if textbox and passwordbox is blank in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm, passwordbox

I basically used a `Model`'s (UserAccount) `Property` from my `ViewModel`(CreateAccountViewModel) to bind to my `View`, and call to my `Command` (CreateAccountCommand).

My `Model`(UserAccount):

```cs
public class UserAccount : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private int _id;
    private string _username;
    private string _password;
    private DateTime _dateTime;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id)); }
    }


    public string Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set { _username = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username)); }
    }



    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { _password = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password)); }
    }


    public DateTime DateCreated
    {
        get { return _dateTime; }
        set { _dateTime = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DateCreated)); }
    }

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My `ViewModel`(CreateAccountViewModel):

```cs
public class CreateAccountViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private UserAccount _userAccount;

    public UserAccount CurrentUserAccount
    {
        get { return _userAccount; }
        set { _userAccount = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentUserAccount)); }
    }

    public ICommand CreateAccountCommand{ get; }

    public CreateAccountViewModel()
    {
        CreateAccountCommand= new CreateAccountCommand(this, Test);
        CurrentUserAccount = new UserAccount();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Random Message");
        //I'm going to put my Create functionality here
    }
}
```

My `View` (CreateAccountView):

```xml
<!--The TextBox for username-->
<TextBox Grid.Column="1"
         Margin="10,0,0,0"
         Text="{Binding Path=CurrentUserAccount.Username, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<!--The PasswordBox for password-->
<components:BindablePasswordBox Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                Password="{Binding Path=CurrentUserAccount.Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

<!--The Create user button-->
<Button Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="0,20,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding CreateAccountCommand}"
        Content="Create Account" />
```

My `Command`(CreateAccountCommand):

```cs
public class CreateAccountCommand: ICommand
{
    private readonly CreateAccountViewModel _viewModel;
    private readonly Action RunCommand;

    public CreateAccountCommand(CreateAccountViewModel viewModel , Action runCommand)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        _viewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;

        RunCommand = runCommand;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {        
        //This is supposed to check whether the Username textbox and Password passwordbox is blank (if both of them are blank, the button should be disabled, else disabled
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_viewModel.CurrentUserAccount.Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_viewModel.CurrentUserAccount.Password);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        RunCommand();
    }

    private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

My `PasswordBox` is bindable because I created a custom `PasswordBox` with `DependencyProperty`:

```cs
public partial class BindablePasswordBox : UserControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Password", typeof(string), typeof(BindablePasswordBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string Password
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PasswordProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
    }

    public BindablePasswordBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //This method will notify us, whenever a password in our passwordBox changes
    private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Password = passwordBox.Password; //sets the value of the DependencyProperty (PasswordProperty)
    }
}
```

My problem here, is that, the button in my `View` does not change enable/disable even if I set my command's `CanExecute` to do so. Am I missing something obvious here? I really have to ask because I've been stuck here since yesterday. (My **Main goal** here is to disable the `Create Account` button if the `Textbox` and `PasswordBox` have no input. Any solutions are okay)

Comment: Also you should probably fully qualify your CreateAccountCommand property in the viewmodel and add the onpropertychanged event notifier

Comment: Did you set the views datacontext to your viewmodel class?

Comment: @NoConnection I will put onpropertychanged() to the `CreateAccountCommand`'s setter?

Comment: @NoConnection I already set the datacontext in the code behind...

Answer (score 2):

Lets do a small refactoring.

- use `CallerMemberNameAttribute` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10595688/1997232) how) to have shorter property setters in vm;
- write once reusable `ICommand` implementation and use it for all commands, see [DelegateCommand](https://www.wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html);
- rise command `CanExecuteChanged` in vm when you change one of command `canExecuted` condition;
- `UserAccount` needs notifications (you have done it in the edit), if it's a model, then you need an extra vm to act as a wrapper, otherwise you wouldn't be able to catch changes done by the bound controls;
- Since the properties of `UserAccount` are part of command `canExecuted`, you need to monitor for them.

With all changes your button using the command should be property enabled/disabled.

Below is *pseudo-code* (can contain mistakes):

---

```
public class CreateAccountViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    UserAccount _userAccount;
    public UserAccount CurrentUserAccount
    {
        get => _userAccount;
        set
        {
            // unsubscribe
            if(_userAccount != null)
                _userAccount -= UserAccount_PropertyChanged;
            _userAccount = value;
            // subscribe
            if(_userAccount != null)
                _userAccount += UserAccount_PropertyChanged;
            // notifications
            OnPropertyChanged(); // shorter syntax with CallerMemberNameAttribute
            CreateAccountCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand CreateAccountCommand { get; }

    public CreateAccountViewModel()
    {
        CurrentUserAccount = new UserAccount();
        CreateAccountCommand = new DelegateCommand(Test,
            o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUserAccount.Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentUserAccount.Password));
    }

    void Test(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Random Message");
        //I'm going to put my Create functionality here
    }

    void UserAccount_PropertyChanged(object sender, NotifyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
        CreateAccountCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); // rise always of check for specific properties changes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CreateAccountCommand` hooks up en event handler to the view model's `PropertyChanged` but there is no such event raised when you set the `Username` and `Password` properties of the `UserAccount` object.

Either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `UserAccount` or bind to wrapper properties of the `CreateAccountViewModel`:

```
public string Username
{
    get { return _userAccount?.Username; }
    set
    {
        if (_userAccount != null)
            _userAccount.Username = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

If you decide to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `UserAccount`, you still need to notify the command when the properties have been updated.

Since your `CurrentUserAccount` property may be set to a new value dynamically, you should remove and add the event handler dynamically:

```
private UserAccount _userAccount;
public UserAccount CurrentUserAccount
{
    get { return _userAccount; }
    set
    {
        if (_userAccount != null)
            _userAccount.PropertyChanged -= OnUserAccountPropertyChanged;
        _userAccount = value;
        if (_userAccount != null)
            _userAccount.PropertyChanged += OnUserAccountPropertyChanged;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentUserAccount));
    }
}

private void OnUserAccountPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
    OnPropertyChanged(null);
```

Comment: I tried putting `INotifyPropertyChanged`  to `UserAccount`, but, it still didn't work... and if I create "wrapper properties", wouldn't that make it redundant? since we can access the `UserAccount`'s properties using the `UserAccount`'s Property? (this is my first time making an `MVVM` app, so I'm quite unfamilliar.

Comment: The properties are not redundant if `UserAccount` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. They add change notification.

Comment: If you decide to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `UserAccount`, you still need to notify the command when the properties have been updated.

Comment: the `UserAccount` class is a model.

Comment: I'll update my post (my new `UserAccount` )

Comment: I have watched a tutorial about MVVM where he "separated" the class to a `Model` class and just access the `Model`'s properties in the ViewModel. I thought that it's the right way to do it. I am still learning about MVVM and how to implement it properly.

Comment: You still need to raise an event to the command when the model is updated. See my edit.

Comment: Did this solve your original issue? Please remember to accept the answer to close the question then.